# How to connect to a hyper-v image using remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, remote-desktop

I am running dev images on my pc using hyper-v.

I would like to connect from my pc to the hyper-v image with remote desktop in order to get a full screen view of the desktop.

- Is there anything that I need to activate on the image for RD to work?
- Anything else that I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to activate remote desktop on the VM as well as open the firewall port on the VM to allow remote access and ensure that the PC you are conncting from is on the same Subnet as the VM if you have setup a different subnet